# Connections on bundles over algebraic variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, connections

I am asking for a reference for the theory of connections on vector bundles over algebraic varieties. I am particularly interested in the notion of Gauss-Manin connection, the notions of torsion, p-curvature and monodromy.

Comment: the textbook of Voisin on Hodge theory does contain an explanation of the construction of GM connection; not sure about the other things you are asking for

Comment: Katz "Nilpotent connections and the monodromy theorem" is an all-time classic.

Comment: García-Raboso A., Rayan S.- *Introduction to Nonabelian Hodge Theory*, chapter 2; [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.1693.pdf ] (arXiv:1406.1693 [math.CV]).